# Is it possible to run Tor with Proxychains using socks4a?

Tags: socks, proxy

I'm trying to configure proxychains to make a port-scan with Nmap, but the file config tells only about SOCKS4 and SOCKS5.

Comment: yes, it is just a proxy for proxychains: use it as a *first* proxy in a chain, then it will work properly

Answer (score 1):

Tor provides a SOCKS4a or SOCKS5 compatible proxy, port 9050 is default for a system daemon/service and 9150 for Tor Browser.

However it will not be compatible with most of nmap's functionality, and you shouldn't be using tor to port scan either. See: [Is there a way to get portscanning (nmap) to work through Whonix?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/is-there-a-way-to-get-portscanning-nmap-to-work-through-whonix)