# Is tsocks necessary?

Tags: tails

Yo, Tails noob here. So if Tails is supposed to route everything through Tor by default, can I just type "nmap [options] [target]" and it will be torified or do I actually need to specify tsocks or something like proxychains before the command itself? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The general consensus is that portscanning is harmful to the Tor network... http://tor.stackexchange.com/a/10531/1730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tails doesn't route everything through Tor.

Tails uses a set of applications that are pre-configured to use Tor and stops applications from sending non-Tor traffic.

As such tsocks would be necessary and is mostly incompatible with `nmap`.

Please see [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/is-there-a-way-to-get-portscanning-nmap-to-work-through-whonix).

*P.S.: quit skiddin'*

*P.P.S: Port scanning over Tor is both harmful to the Tor network and mostly ineffective. See [this comment](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/is-there-a-way-to-get-portscanning-nmap-to-work-through-whonix#comment10570_10531)*

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answering. I see now that tsocks or just setting the --proxy flag would indeed be the way to go for nmap use on Tails. However, I must disagree with you on a few points. Port scanning is probably pretty low on Tor's worry list when compared to, gee, I don't know, maybe heavy torrenting and botnet traffic and DDoSing and basically everything else. Also, it is not always very noisy. See here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19576/what-scanning-tools-are-unlikely-to-set-off-network-ids

Comment: And if nmap is "ineffective" and qualifies as "skiddin" then surely a grandmaster haxx0r like yourself must know a better way? If not, then I urge you to check your facts before hating on a very well known, professionally used tool.

Comment: Ok, well I'm just here to learn so if you wouldn't mind telling me about this "better than nmap" port scanning technique, I would honestly love to hear it. You seem very knowledgeable.

Comment: Try the kali linux forums for tips on being a skid.